# Python convert xls with multiple worksheets to csv without newlines or bytes

Tags: python

Code below takes an xls file and destination path. The code loops through all the worksheets in each file and converts the to a pipe delimited csv file.

```
def ExceltoCSV(excel_file, csv_file_base_path):
    head, tail = os.path.split(excel_file)
    print(tail)
    workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(excel_file)
    for sheet_name in workbook.sheet_names():
        print('processing - ' + sheet_name)
        worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name(sheet_name)
        csv_file_full_path = csv_file_base_path + sheet_name.lower().replace(" - ", "_").replace(" ","_") + '.csv'
        csvfile = open(csv_file_full_path, 'w')
        writetocsv = csv.writer(csvfile, quoting = csv.QUOTE_ALL, delimiter='|')
        for rownum in range(worksheet.nrows):
             writetocsv.writerow(list((x.encode('utf-8')).decode() if type(x) == type(u'') else x for x in worksheet.row_values(rownum)))
        csvfile.close()
        print(sheet_name + ' has been saved at - ' + csv_file_full_path)
```

My issue with the function is that it creates the file  with a \n after each line and it wraps each valve it writes inside "b'value'". I have tried the open with the wb option but I get an error:
***a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'***

what should i change to avoid the extra lines and the wrapping of "b''"

Sample file output

```
"b''"|"b'Totals'"|"b'321'"|"b'734'"|"b'2,941,740'"|"b''"|"b''"|"b'Under - 11 Totals'"|"b'203'"|"b'77'"|"b''"|"b''"

"b''"|"b''"|"b''"|"b''"|"b''"|"b''"|"b''"|"b''"|"b''"|"b''"|"b''"|"b''"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert bytes to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606191/convert-bytes-to-a-string)

Comment: Thanks for response but no

Comment: "<built-in method decode of bytes object at 0x0000016D7B09BC90>"|"<built-in method decode of bytes object at 0x0000016D761E80D0>"|"<built-in method decode of bytes object at 0x0000016D761E80D0>"|"<built-in method decode of bytes object at 0x0000016D761E80D0>"|"<built-in method decode of bytes object at 0x0000016D761E80D0>"|"<built-in method decode of bytes object at 0x0000016D761E80D0>"|"<built-in method decode of bytes object at

Comment: Can u edit the post with the updated code, its looks like you have missing `()` you have just ``.decode`` instead it should be ``.decode()``

Comment: Decode line below

Comment: writetocsv.writerow(list((x.encode('utf-8')).decode if type(x) == type(u'') else x for x in worksheet.row_values(rownum)))

Comment: as mentioned in above commend it should be ``..(x.encode('utf-8')).decode()...``, its a func call

Comment: thank you for clarification. Correction made now have a unicode error

Comment: UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2264' in position 77: character maps to

Comment: Decode line has been updates in original question.

Comment: Try opening the file as `wb`?

Comment: Thank you drum.. as stated above wb does not work. Tried it again got the same error

Comment: TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: i have my answer. Modified Function below

Comment: def ExceltoCSV2(excel_file, csv_file_base_path):
     head, tail = os.path.split(excel_file)
     df = pd.DataFrame()
     xl = pd.ExcelFile(excel_file)

     for sheet in xl.sheet_names:
         df_tmp = xl.parse(sheet)
         df = df.append(df_tmp, ignore_index=True,sort=False)
         print(len(df))
         csvfile = head+'/'+sheet+'.csv'
         print(csvfile)
         df.to_csv(csvfile, index=False, sep='|')